# Sorted Key value pairs for millions of entries

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary, treemap

TreeMap is an efficient data structure to keep key value pairs in a sorted order. In my scenario I have around 200 millions of key value pairs to manage through java program. I could see observe my TreeMap performance visibly slow when more than 12 millions key values are supplied to it. What is the correct way harness the TreeMap potential. Is this the TreeMap limitations.
Even If I manage to put all the key value pairs how do I ensure faster retrieval from this map.
I can not use key value pairs DB.

Comment: Can you quantify "performance visibly slow"?

Comment: What are your memory heap size settings?

Comment: very likely slowness is caused by intensive work of GC: 12M entries in `TreeMap` occupy ~300Mb in heap (not taking into account key and value objects themselves). For 200M it will be ~5Gb (and also just for entries, keys and values not included). What is your `-Xmx` setting and do you have enough free physical memory?

Comment: Personally I avoid TreeMap. HashMap is much faster as basic operations are O(1). If you need to iterate in key order you can iterate over `new TreeSet<>(map.keySet())` instead. This increases cost of iteration to `O(n log n)` but makes everything else much faster. Only use a `TreeMap` if it is necessary for the keys to be sorted at all times.